# Need help with Jquery and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have bunch of employees, each employee have 7 days for their work schedule. I created the following form using php and would like get data from here to JavaScript for verification and then submit it to SQL database using ajax. My problem is how can I dynamically create these forms and then get values from their inputs? Dynamically creating them is the easy part.

```
<?php
 function getNewEmployeeForm($name) {

$def_form = "
  <tr name=\"" . $name ."\">
  <td>".$name ."</td>
    <td>
        <input style=\"width:55px\" id='". $name ."' type=\"text\">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input style=\"width:55px\" id='". $name ."' type=\"text\">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input style=\"width:55px\" id='". $name ."' type=\"text\">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input style=\"width:55px\" id='". $name ."' type=\"text\">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input style=\"width:55px\" id='". $name ."' type=\"text\">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input style=\"width:55px\" id='". $name ."' type=\"text\">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input style=\"width:55px\" id='". $name ."' type=\"text\">
    </td>
  </tr>";

  echo $def_form;
}?>
```

Comment: That's not valid html. Two elements cannot have the same id.

Comment: I tried, var arr = $(":input#name"); didn't work.

Comment: how can name or id them so i can get all the inputs, given a user name.

Comment: I believe you wanted to use class attribute rather than id

Comment: it works sitebloviate.com, it creates 7 input fields. Is is possible to use <div name="empName"> ?

Comment: I think, before trying anything, you should first think about what you wnat. Your question contains about 8 questions, and you seem to miss some basic information. Break up your problem. You don't need any javascript or jquery to post a form. Try to save fixed/hardcoded data first. If that works, create a simple dynamic HTML form and try to process the posted. Only after everything works you start enhancing it using javascript/jquery to improve usability.

Comment: No need in naming a div. `Name` is used for posting forms and a div is no input field.

Comment: there is no need to put that in a function as your not `return`ing the result your just echoing it

Comment: @Lawrence. Could still be handy to group/structure the code in a way. Though code structure I think is the least of his troubles.

Comment: Some issues: 1) I don't think you understand what an ID attribute is. It is a unique identifier, and thus only one element in a document can have a given ID. 2) You need to make a regular form submit first. In such a case you want to use a _unique_ `name` for each input ("j-smith-0", "john-smith-1", etc.). 3) I don't think you understand `for` loops, otherwise you'd probably iterate `i` from `0` to `6`, concatenate that with the employee name, and make that the `<input>`'s `name`. 4) jQuery has no `":input"` selector. Bottom line is, you need to understand HTML forms before trying AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a 'name' attribute and give it a value for example 'day'

Then try the following javascript (untested)

```
var employees = new Array();

$('table td input[name="day"]').each(function(i){
    employees[i] = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: the table thing didn't work but this did, (':input.Name'). Thank you all for your help and comments